# How to move files to another folder in php

Tags: php, file

I have 4 csv files in "files" folder & I want to move these files with content to another folder (i.e. backups),Files are given below.

1. abc.csv
2. abc1.csv
3. abc2.csv

```js
$files = scandir('files');
$destination = 'backups/';
$date = date('Y-m-d');
foreach($files as $file){
    $rename_file = $file.'_'.$date;
    move_uploaded_file($rename_file, "$destination");
}
```

Comment: Since you are not uploading any files, try `rename()` function instead.

Comment: http://php.net/rename

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not uploading any files, try `rename()` function instead.

```
$Ignore = array(".","..","Thumbs.db");
$OriginalFileRoot = "files";
$OriginalFiles = scandir($OriginalFileRoot);
$DestinationRoot = "backups";
# Check to see if "backups" exists
if(!is_dir($DestinationRoot)){
    mkdir($DestinationRoot,0777,true);
}
$Date = date('Y-m-d');
foreach($OriginalFiles as $OriginalFile){
    if(!in_array($OriginalFile,$Ignore)){
        $FileExt = pathinfo($OriginalFileRoot."\\".$OriginalFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // Get the file extension
        $Filename = basename($OriginalFile, ".".$FileExt); // Get the filename
        $DestinationFile = $DestinationRoot."\\".$Filename.'_'.$Date.".".$FileExt; // Create the destination filename 
        rename($OriginalFileRoot."\\".$OriginalFile, $DestinationFile); // rename the file            
    }
}
```

Comment: complex code, but you got my vote based on the edit to my answer :) thanks!

Comment: @Dekel Yeah, a bit complex, but thought the extra variables were worth mentioning :)

Comment: @JustBaron I have used your code but I am getting error "No such file or directory "

Comment: The code works for me. I suggest debugging to see which file/directory does not exist. I'll update my answer to help you check for this.

Comment: I got error PHP Warning: rename(files/\abc.csv,backups/\abc_2017-08-11.csv) : No such file or directory  3 times

Comment: Because you have not used my code. Check the names of your directories, i.e. remove the "/" from "files/" and "backups/".

Comment: I updated your this line rename($OriginalFileRoot."\\".$OriginalFile, $DestinationFile); to rename($OriginalFileRoot.$OriginalFile, $DestinationFile);  Its working file but I found files name are \abc_2017-08-11.csv just like & "files/", "backups/" it's working fine

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that ;)...But if it answers your question and it helps, feel free to accept the answer (+ upvote) :)

Comment: Thanks @JustBaron I modify your code & I have reached to output Thanks once again your valuable inputs :)

Answer (score 3):

The function `move_uploaded_file` is relevant for uploading files, not for other things.

To move file in the filesystem you should use the [`rename`](http://php.net/rename) function:

```
$files = scandir('files');
$destination = 'backups/';
$date = date('Y-m-d');
foreach($files as $file){
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        continue;
    }
    $rename_file = $destination.$file.'_'.$date;
    rename($file, $rename_file);
}
```

Comment: I need this files move into the backup folder ,How is it possible

Comment: I missed the `$destination` there, check the updated based on @JustBaron edit to my answer.

Comment: @JustBaron source file directory is 'files/', this is correct ? but files not found in backup folder when I run this script & no error display

Comment: @Shreya check my answer